# Keep getting NaN instead of 0

Tags: javascript

This is a function that retrieves results from Bing and populates an Object array.

```
callBing: function (query, callback) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/meta/public/bing/'+query ; 
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        total_bing = data.d.results[0].WebTotal;
        var j = 0 ;
        $.each(data.d.results[0].Web, function() {
            var obj = new res(j+1, this.Title, this.Description, this.Url, 0) ; 
            b.push(obj) ; 
            j=j+1 ;
        });
        console.log(b);
        callback(b, total_bing);
    });
},
```

And this is the constructor for the res objects

```
function res(id,title,desc,url,score)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.title=title;
    this.desc=desc;
    this.url=url;
    this.score=score;
    this.changeRankScore=changeRankScore;
    function changeRankScore(Rankscore)
    {
        this.score=Rankscore;
        return Rankscore; 
    }


}
```

As you can see, when each result is retrieved for the constructor, it populates the array with the results object.

The results objects' score is the last parameter in the constructor which is 0 but it is displaying as **`NaN`** in the console.

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Don't you call your changeRankScore function somewhere ? For example without argument.

Comment: you might be getting `"0"` instead of `0` convert fist into int type.

Comment: Note that in Chrome console when you open an object you see it in it's current state, not in the state when `console.log` was called, i.e. `callback(b, total_bing);` might be the culprit.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan How would that explain `NaN`? Not to mention that he is explicitly setting `score` to `0` (he's not getting it from anywhere).

Comment: And jsFiddle to demonstrate what I was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/3ymx6/ Note that in console score is 1, although it was set later.

Comment: Please explain, how or where are you passing the `Rankscore` param to function `changeRankScore`??

Comment: @freakish hmm you are correct.

Comment: Freakish was spot on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @freakish said, it's possible that the `score` has been changed after calling `console.log`, but `console.log` happened to show the changed value.

You may try `console.log(b[0].score)` before and after `callback`